# How do I momentarily remove :hover from the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

here's a jsfiddle with my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/sbBxu/ - when you hover the "Hover me" element, the .result gets hidden by the list. When the user clicks any of the "click me" elements, the result changes, but the user doesn't see it.

I want to let the user see the result, which is hidden by `.hidden`. But if I just "hide" it, JQuery sets the "display" property to "none", which breaks the show-on-hover behavior.

Basically, I want the same stuff as in the fiddle, except the popup hides on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just remove the `:hover` from the css, and use jQuery for showing/hiding the list:

http://jsfiddle.net/sbBxu/4/

```
$('.hoverd').mouseenter(function () {
  $('.hidden', this).show();
});

$('.hidden li').click(function() {
  $('.result').text('I am a result');
  $(this).closest('.hidden').hide();
});
```

Comment: @Fluffy Of course, but what about the "Click me" then? This would also not work for users without js.

Comment: You're right, I guess there is no way the underlying content can be changed without JS (or flash or other plugin)

Answer (score 2):

Try removing `position: absolute` from your `.hoverd:hover .hidden` class.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/sbBxu/2/)

Comment: I do need position - the popup must be above everything, namely the `.result`

Comment: That's a strange UI you have then, if an element contains a value which must be visible, yet is covered by another element?

Comment: Well, I would imagine, css popups are rather common. Haven't you seen navigation, which expands, when you hover it?

Comment: I have, but not so that it covers another element which must be visible.

Comment: Either way, that's what I need and I can't change it